# SQL Query works in phpMyAdmin but not in php page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird problem happening:

I have a php page that compiles and executes a MySQL query to my web database.  The goal is to try and determine if a point is within a polygon, using a custom non-MBR spatial relation function.

The query returns a syntax error result 1064.

Here is the echoed query that displays on my page:

```
SET @point = 'POINT(-63.610719000 44.669318000)'; SELECT * FROM `Zones` WHERE GISWithin(GeomFromText(@point), `zonePoly`) AND `zoneName` = 'trailerShareBoundary';
```

If I copy and paste that query string into phpMyAdmin, it works like a charm.

However, when the query originates from my php page, the following error is returned:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM `Zones` WHERE GISWithin(GeomFromText(@point), `zonePoly`) AND `zon' at line 1(1064)
```

And here is the php code that makes this all happen:

```
    if(!is_null($lng) && !is_null($lat)){

    //Create a mySQL variable to store a MySQL POINT object
    $query= "SET @point = 'POINT(".$lng." ".$lat.")'; ";

    //Test if the POINT variable is within the trailerShareBoundary variable using
    //custom MySQL function
    $query.= "SELECT * FROM `Zones` WHERE GISWithin(GeomFromText(@point), `zonePoly`) AND `zoneName` = 'trailerShareBoundary';";
    echo "<br/>".$query."<br/>";

    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    var_dump($result);
    echo '<br/>';

    if(!$result==false){
        $instructions = "<p>LOCK REQUEST VALID</p>";
    }else{
        $instructions = "<p>LOCK REQUEST INVALID</p>";
        echo mysqli_error($connection) . "(" . mysqli_errno($connection) . ")";
    }
    echo $instructions;

}
```

I've figured out a work-around:

If I first query the database to create the @point variable, then create a SEPARATE QUERY to query the database with my SELECT statement, it magically works!  Here's what I mean:

This works:

```
    //Create a mySQL variable to store a MySQL POINT object
    $query= "SET @point = 'POINT(".$lng." ".$lat.")'; ";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    echo "<br/>".$query."<br/>";
    //Test if the POINT variable is within the trailerShareBoundary variable using
    //custom MySQL function
    $query= "SELECT * FROM `Zones` WHERE GISWithin(GeomFromText(@point), `zonePoly`) AND `zoneName` = 'trailerShareBoundary';";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    echo "<br/>".$query."<br/>";
```

So, can anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_query` does not allow multiple queries, use `mysqli_multi_query`

This should work:

```
//Create a mySQL variable to store a MySQL POINT object
$query = "SET @point = 'POINT(".$lng." ".$lat.")'; ";

$query .= "SELECT * FROM `Zones` WHERE GISWithin(GeomFromText(@point), `zonePoly`) AND `zoneName` = 'trailerShareBoundary';";
$result=mysqli_multi_query($connection,$query);
echo "<br/>".$query."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you were appending the first query with second one. And has also used semicolon in the query inside program . This is why first was showing error.